# How can I insert separator characters in a xmllint query that returns several results

Tags: xml, shell, applescript, xmllint

Hello all you clever people :-)
I'm calling a shell script from AppleScript to fetch values from an xml file. The file (simplified!) looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<ProductHints spec="1.0.16">
  <Product version="4">
    <Name>The Product Name</Name>
    <Company>The Company Name</Company>
    <PRODID>A123</PRODID>
  </Product>
</ProductHints>
```

My AppleScript looks like this :

```
set thePath to "/Path/to/my/file.xml"
set theResult to do shell script "xmllint " & quoted form of thepath & " --xpath '/ProductHints/Product/Name/text() | /ProductHints/Product/PRODID/text() | /ProductHints/Product/Company/text()'"
display dialog theResult
```

As a result, this displays :
The Product NameThe Company NameA123

This is indeed the required information, but not much use as it is !
I would like the result to be either tab separated or comma separated (tab would be ideal, but I could work with comma !) for example :

```
The Product Name **Tab** The Company Name **Tab** A123
```

or

```
The Product Name, The Company Name, A123
```

I'm sure there's a simple solution to place something in between each item, but I've tried various things to no avail !

Could any kind soul help me out here please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The results you show would indeed be what I'd like to obtain, and there are indeed other names, product IDs and companies in OTHER xml files that I scan. The "simplification" was just not showing other tags like <internalID>…</internalID> etc. which are of no interest to me.

Comment: All I need are the three that I sited from each xml file that I parse, separated by commas or tabs (or something).The recovered info from each xml is then collected into a summary text file in three columns, hence my preference for tabs, but I can obviously convert commas or something else into tabs if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ooooops ! That code block was a bit of a mess. I'll try again :

```
set thepath to "/Path/to/My/file name.xml"
 set theScript to "xmllint --xpath \"concat(/ProductHints/Product/Name/text(),',',/ProductHints/Product/PRODID/text(),',',/ProductHints/Product/Company/text())\" " & quoted form of thepath
 set theResult to do shell script theScript without altering line endings
display dialog theResult
```